# Safari (Webkit) displays shadow incorrectly (filter: drop-shadow)

Tags: html, css, webkit

I recently created a searchbar with a shadow effect on hover, it works correctly on all browsers except on Safari (Desktop), tested on Version 13.1.1 (15609.2.9.1.2). There the shadow seems to not go out of the div.

The shadow was created with

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
```

I also tried -webkit-filter unsuccessfully. As well as fixing it with overflow: visible

Here is a short vid of the bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQw4W.jpg

You can test it yourself by creating this html file

```css
.searchbar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px gray solid;
}

.searchbar:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbar"></div>
```

Comment: sorry, created a minimal example now

Comment: What's version Safari?

Comment: I tested it on Safari Version 13.1.1 (15609.2.9.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using box-shadow instead of filter drop-shadow

```css
.searchbar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  transition: filter .1s;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 5px rgba(255, 255,255, 0));
}

.searchbar:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1));
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbar"></div>
```

Comment: this did not solve it for me, I added a minimal example above

Comment: since drop-shadow has some special properties i cannot use  box-shadow in my case